# eBay API findItemsAdvanced() returns duplicate results for variation listings

Tags: javascript, ebay-api

The eBay API functions

```
findItemsAdvanced() or findItemsByKeywords()
```

return all variations for variation listings. How can I prevent getting multiple results for the same listing?

Currently my page on eBay is doing just that from the variations of [this listing](http://www.ebay.com/itm/262458257838?var=&ssPageName=STRK:MESELX:IT&_trksid=p3984.m1555.l2649)
 and you can see the results [here](http://gavdials.com/index.php/on-ebay).

How can I have the variation results combined into just one result per listing?

Here's the code as the tutorial show from eBay:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>eBay Search Results</title>
    <style type="text/css">body { font-family: arial,sans-serif;} </style>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <h1>eBay Search Results</h1>

    <div id="results"></div>

    <script>

    // Parse the response and build an HTML table to display search results
    function _cb_findItemsByKeywords(root) {
      var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
      var html = [];
      html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tbody>');
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var item     = items[i];
        var title    = item.title;
        var pic      = item.galleryURL;
        var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
        if (null != title && null != viewitem) {
          html.push('<tr><td>' + '<img src="' + pic + '" border="0">' + '</td>' + 
          '<td><a href="' + viewitem + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></td></tr>');
        }
      }
      html.push('</tbody></table>');
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");
    }  // End _cb_findItemsByKeywords() function

    // Create a JavaScript array of the item filters you want to use in your request
    var filterarray = [
      {"name":"Seller",
       "value":"gavdials-com"},
      //{"name":"FreeShippingOnly", 
       //"value":"true", 
       //"paramName":"", 
       //"paramValue":""},
      ];


    // Define global variable for the URL filter
    var urlfilter = "";

    // Generates an indexed URL snippet from the array of item filters
    function  buildURLArray() {
      // Iterate through each filter in the array
      for(var i=0; i<filterarray.length; i++) {
        //Index each item filter in filterarray
        var itemfilter = filterarray[i];
        // Iterate through each parameter in each item filter
        for(var index in itemfilter) {
          // Check to see if the paramter has a value (some don't)
          if (itemfilter[index] !== "") {
            if (itemfilter[index] instanceof Array) {
              for(var r=0; r<itemfilter[index].length; r++) {
              var value = itemfilter[index][r];
              urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "\(" + r + "\)=" + value ;
              }
            } 
            else {
              urlfilter += "&itemFilter\(" + i + "\)." + index + "=" + itemfilter[index];
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }  // End buildURLArray() function

    // Execute the function to build the URL filter
    buildURLArray(filterarray);

    // Construct the request
    // Replace MyAppID with your Production AppID
    var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
        url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords";
        url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
        url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=MyAppID";
        url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
        url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
        url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords";
        url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
        url += "&keywords=markers";
        url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=100";
        url += urlfilter;


    // Submit the request 
    s=document.createElement('script'); // create script element
    s.src= url;
    document.body.appendChild(s);

    // Display the request as a clickable link for testing
    document.write("<a href=\"" + url + "\">" + url + "</a>");

    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show the code you have already so that I can see where it needs adjusting?

Comment: @JamesNewbert-Breen I've added the simple code from the tutorial of eBay with my own username...: http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/howto/GettingStarted_JS_NV_JSON/GettingStarted_JS_NV_JSON.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the item filter "HideDuplicateItems"?

Also, in the future, always be sure to mask your eBay API credentials when posting publicly.

Comment: You were correct. it works now. Can you tell me how I should mask the credentials please? and what is the problem with that. Thanks @helios825

Comment: Your credentials are your AppID in this case -- which appears publicly in your code up above. Others can steal your AppID and abuse it, affecting your access to the eBay API in various ways. To mask it, edit it in your original question to be something like "xxxxxxxxxxxxx".